# WP_Query with 'rand', but equal number of posts from the taxonomy terms given

Tags: wp-query, query

I have two terms in a taxonomy that I'm attempting to fetch equal amounts of posts from. Of course, if the `posts_per_page` is an odd number, I wouldn't get a truly "equal" number of posts; but we can try to get close.

If the `posts_per_page` is 4, I would expect two posts from each of the categories. However, if the `posts_per_page` is 5, I would expect 3 and 2 to equal 5.

What I'm hoping to avoid is the situation when a `posts_per_page` of 5 gives me 4 and 1; or rather worse 5 and 0.

I'm contemplating something where I do multiple queries, join the IDs, then using `post__in` to join everything back together into one query...but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suppose looking at `ORDER BY RAND()` in MySQL maybe paints a different picture for this application. As I understand it, MySQL gets all possible results into an array, then assigns an index to them, then randomly picks whatever the number was. This would mean it to be truly "random", in which case maybe `rand` is the wrong way to think about this problem.